# Pre-program a song in synthesia

Tags: piano, songwriting

Is there a way to "program" or script a song in synthesia (or another piano software, in this case please suggest one).

Basically, I like composing music, but I suck at playing it. The music I write probably isn't that good, since my sense of rythm and my ear are both bad, but I still like doing it.

I'd like some instant feedback as to how specific segments sound. Obviously a great software for that is [Synthesia](http://www.synthesiagame.com/).

My problem is that, even after writing it, it takes me several tries to play it correctly, and it ends up being a huge loss of time.

I'm looking for either a way to do this in synthesia, or another software that would allow me to pre-enter (I don't care how) which notes should be played when and for how long, and the program would play it back to me. I'm more of a piano kind of guy, but of course having other instruments available is no problem. I just need the piano option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like entering musical notes, scorewriters such as Musescore or the paid Finale/Sibelius are good.